# How to implement NSOperationQueue in right way

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I am new in operation queue, so give me flexibility to ask that question which may ask already meanwhile I searched a lot but not able to find my desired solution.

I have a API which delete single document and its working fine via using `AFNetworking`(which take documentID as param and accesstoken). Now I want to delete multiples document the solution should be that I should have another API which takes array or string (comma separated).

As far as I know the solution should be to call that API into Loop and delete all, but I heard another solution which is `NSOperationQueue`. I saw tutorial but I am not able to use those in right manner.
Here below is my code to call one operation.

```
    NSString *jsonString = @"";
NSString *authorizationValue = [self setAuthorizationValue:action];
NSString *language = @"en_US";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:language forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:authorizationValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];

//convert parameters in to json data

if ([params isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:action]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:500.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:postBody];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

So kindly guide me how call this in operation queue, do I need to create these call and put into array and then add those into operation queue.

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
// Set the max number of concurrent operations (threads)
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3];
[operationQueue addOperations:@[operation] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```

Looking for your response.
Thanks

Comment: You should note, that while you can correctly implement an approach using `NSOperationQueue`  - it's not the _optimal_ way to solve this problem. This approach has a number of (small) caveats - but it's usually sufficient, if our requirements are moderate. If you want to squeeze the best out of your device - there are better approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> the solution should be that I should have another API which takes array or string (comma separated)

This would be the best solution, yes, because it minimise the workload of the client and the server and makes the smallest number of network requests possible - it's fast and efficient.

> the solution should be to call that API into Loop and delete all, but I heard another solution which is `NSOperationQueue`

Using an operation queue is better than running in a loop because you have control over the timing (how many operations run concurrently), which you already show in your code.

The only issue with your code is calling `NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];` each time before adding the new operation. Instead of doing that you should create and configure the operation queue once and store a strong reference to it. Otherwise you have lots of different operation queues each executing operations concurrently and your setting of `setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:3` means nothing.

Comment: Do I need to have a separate class which is creating object of "AFHTTPRequestOperation" and then add into array like requestOperationArray and then add this array into NSOperationQueue?
Plus how can we differentiate or track each request?
I need bit help on this to implement.

Comment: yes, using a custom class with this responsibility is a sensible approach. tracking is a different question, how do you want to track it??

Comment: Thats where I am confused that how do I need to track ?

Comment: I see one another tutorial where using "[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:" so whats difference between to use this or addOperations ?

Comment: it uses the main queue instead of a background queue, either should be fine for you. it also uses block operations, but you already have operations so you don't need that part.

Comment: I have wrap up this problem over here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35129928/how-to-trigger-nsoperationqueue-and-get-results-in-block-of-multiple-operation
kindly guide me where I am doing wrong