# How to trigger NSOperationQueue and get results in block of multiple operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue

I already asked question related to `NSOperationQueue` but I am still around of implementing operation queue with multiples operation. I have following code

```
    NSMutableArray * operationArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i =0; i<[documentModelList count]; i++) {
    DocumentModel * documentModel = [documentModelList objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@/%li", SERVER_URL, DOCUMENTS_DELETE,(long)documentModel.documentID];
    [operationArray addObject:[AppHttpClient getDeleteRequest:nil urlQuery:url]];
}
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
// Set the max number of concurrent operations (threads)
[operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:operationArray.count];
[operationQueue addOperations:operationArray waitUntilFinished:NO];



+ (AFHTTPRequestOperation *) getDeleteRequest:(NSDictionary *)headerParams urlQuery: (NSString*)action
{

NSString *jsonString = @"";
NSString *authorizationValue = [self setAuthorizationValue:action];
NSString *language = @"en_US";

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:language forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:authorizationValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:action]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:500.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

return operation;
}
```

The above code creating operations in loop and adding into `operationArray` and then add this operation array into `operationQueue`. Now I want to trigger that and get response of whole array.

**Edited**

```
+ (void) gernalDeleteRequest:(NSDictionary *)headerParams urlQuery: (NSString*)action parameters:(NSDictionary*)params
            onComplete:(void (^)(id json, id code))successBlock
               onError:(void (^)(id error, id code))errorBlock
{
    NSString *jsonString = @"";
    NSString *authorizationValue = [self setAuthorizationValue:action];
    NSString *language = @"en_US";



NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:language forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];
[request setValue:authorizationValue forHTTPHeaderField:@"authorization"];

//convert parameters in to json data

if ([params isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&error];
    jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:action]];
[request setTimeoutInterval:500.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"DELETE"];
NSMutableData *postBody = [NSMutableData data];
[postBody appendData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[request setHTTPBody:postBody];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];

operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    NSInteger statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];
    NSNumber *statusObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:statusCode];
    successBlock(responseObject, statusObject);
    NSLog(@"authentication success");

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSInteger statusCode = [operation.response statusCode];
    NSNumber *statusObject = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:statusCode];

    id responseObject = operation.responseData;
    id json = nil;
    NSString *errorMessage = nil;

    if (responseObject) {

        json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];
        errorMessage = [(NSDictionary*)json objectForKey:@"Message"];
    }else{
        json = [error.userInfo objectForKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey];
        errorMessage = json;
    }

    errorBlock(errorMessage, statusObject);

}];

[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperation:operation];
```

}

Comment: so you just want to know when all operations in `operationArray` are complete ?

Comment: Yes and how to trigger and get response ?

Comment: which response? each operation will give a different response

Comment: @Wain can we have a chat ?

Comment: I need your few time to implement this, i am getting confuse on implementing.

Comment: Response of each "AFHTTPRequestOperation", If you look at my code there is no way to catch each operation response.

Answer (score 0):

For the overall status you can create another operation, which can be a block operation, and which uses `addDependency:` to ensure that it runs after all of the other operations are complete. Add the dependencies in the loop where you create each delete operation.

For each individual status you need to use `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` to get feedback about the results.

Comment: Kindly see code under Edited, like this you are saying?

Comment: that's correct for the status handling - i guess you don't really need to track now?

Comment: If we use this, I mean to handle one by one then what will the purpose to use NSOperationQueue, On both using NSOperationQueue or without NSOperationQueue at the end I am using loop and handling one by one then what real advantage to use NSOperationQueue?

Comment: the advantage is to ensure that you don't make too many concurrent requests. if you send more than perhaps around 6 concurrent requests you can flood the network and they will all timeout and fail...

Comment: Thanks, so can you please finally code how to use nsoperationqueue using my above code ?

Comment: based on my current understanding of your requirement you simply need to change `[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]` to `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]`